# query "...WHERE $string"... $string='b5KlL4znM ' but query returns empty unless "...WHERE 'b5KlL4znM ' "

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, alphanumeric

I am trying to get some information from my table, but the query returns empty when I call it this way:

```
$varchar_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['code']); //the code is b5KlL4znM in this scenario

mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE code = $varchar_string");
```

The string is alphanumeric, and is submitted by users, so I've escaped it before doing the query.

Now if I do this query

```
mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE code = 'b5KlL4znM'");
```

It works fine, but that's not very dynamic.

I didn't get many results when I searched for this issue, and I didn't manage to find the answer amongst those that seem relevant.

Comment: Try surrounding your variable in single quotes

Comment: Also, in the future you might want to try logging what the sql string is you are forming, so you can see where these sorts of things go wrong.  Also, parameterized queries are your friend, and are much more secure.

Comment: That's the best title you could think of?

Comment: @nickb in fairness, the title does show exactly what the problem is... But I agree, it is a bad title.

Comment: I was certain I had tried that. Sorry. But thanks to both/all three.

About the title, you're right, it won't help someone with a similar problem much.

Comment: Still a horrible title, but slightly more informative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to include the variable in quotations.

```
mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE code = '$varchar_string'");
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you perhaps need to put quotes around your string?

```
mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE code = '$varchar_string'");
```

Comment: As I recall I already did that, going to try again though. And that might take a while, it seems that the host is down.